# AbstractMethodError when adding file download control to xpage

Tags: java, xpages

In one of our apps we currently are facing the a strange issue involving download controls. When we add a file download control to the xpage and bind it to the datasource ( normal Document source) we receive the following error ( see stacktrace on bottom of the question.

We are using Domino 9.0.1 FP3 and the domino openntf api plugins. Because a search on this issue didn't give us any insight into the issue we hope that someone can explain what is happening and how to solve it.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: lotus/domino/EmbeddedObject.getFileModified()Llotus/domino/DateTime;
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.handleError(FacesServlet.java:648)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.renderErrorPage(FacesServlet.java:482)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:183)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:350)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:306)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: lotus/domino/EmbeddedObject.getFileModified()Llotus/domino/DateTime;
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument$AttachmentValueHolder.<init>(DominoDocument.java:1939)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoRichTextItem.buildAttachmentListRT(DominoRichTextItem.java:2224)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoRichTextItem.getAttachmentList(DominoRichTextItem.java:2200)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument.readFieldAttachments(DominoDocument.java:2080)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument.getAttachmentList(DominoDocument.java:2152)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoAttachmentDataModel.getAttachments(DominoAttachmentDataModel.java:58)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoAttachmentDataModel.<init>(DominoAttachmentDataModel.java:39)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDataModelFactory.createDataModel(DominoDataModelFactory.java:68)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ApplicationExImpl.createDataModel(ApplicationExImpl.java:461)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIFileDownload.isRendered(UIFileDownload.java:485)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.fillShadowedFlags(UIComponentBase.java:880)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:948)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:788)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataEx.encodeBegin(UIDataEx.java:425)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:842)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(FacesUtil.java:873)
    at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:206)
    at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:844)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(FacesUtil.java:873)
    at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:206)
    at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:844)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(FacesUtil.java:873)
    at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:206)
    at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:844)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(FacesUtil.java:873)
    at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:206)
    at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:844)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(FacesUtil.java:873)
    at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:206)
    at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:844)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx._renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1317)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1255)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doRender(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:651)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:321)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:336)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:103)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:120)
    at com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(FacesControllerImpl.java:270)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:261)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure OpenNTF Domino API isn't affecting things here. It's using DominoDocument class and we only override the back-end Domino classes. That's confirmed by no "org.openntf.domino..." classes in the stack trace.

Comment: correct, that was something I already noticed in the stacktrace. I only mention it to give a complete picture of the environment.

Comment: What happens if you omit the "show modified" option in the download control? It seems there is a problem regarding this date property.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference. For some reason that property is calculated always.

Comment: After some testing I noticed something. When we created a document with a single richtextitem no errors where generated. As soon as I added a second richtextitem the problem started to occur.. sometimes.

Comment: I thought I had a solution by creating a separate document for the uploads which is a response to the original document but as you probably can imagine. This also returns the above error when saving a second attachment to the response. 

I think there is something going on in one of the validation phases since the document is not even saved.

Comment: Did you notice out of place 'L' in the 'caused by' in the stack trace: lotus/domino/EmbeddedObject.getFileModified()Llotus/domino/DateTime;
I don't know what to make of it but it looks wierd.

Comment: When you mention the second RichTextItem, is it a second file attached to the same RT field or a separate RT field with a different name? Also your RT field properties, is your "Store contents as HTML and MIME" checked or not? Any other querySave events (e.g.- document data source compute with form)?

Comment: @EricMcCormick there are no documents attached to the second rt field. This second field is only for saving text input to users.  

the rt field that holds the attachments does have the Store content as html and mime checked.

Comment: can you make a new xpage with the isolated problem and post the code here so we can try it?

Comment: What @ThomasAdrian s aid.

Answer (score 1):

*java.lang.AbstractMethodError* occurs if the definition of some class has incompatibly changed since the currently executing method was last compiled.

I think the the underlying method is returning an array of Llotus/domino/DateTime objects but the source code @ *https://github.com/OpenNTF/org.openntf.domino/blob/master/org.openntf.domino/src/org/openntf/domino/impl/EmbeddedObject.java* says it expects single object